# What is the difference between a Canon EF and EF-S lens?

Tags: lens, canon, equipment-recommendation, canon-550d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses)

I read [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean/508#508):

> EF: Electronic Focus
>
> EF-S: Short-Back Electronic Focus

Is the difference significant? How much will it matter in practical?

---

Background:

I am trying to choose between the Canon EOS Rebel T2i options available on internet.

[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MAKXMA) and [B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&A=ShowProduct&sku=680673&is=REG&Q=) are way costly as compared to this [Adorama deal](http://www.adorama.com/ICADRT2IK2B.html), but it says

> ... with EF 18-135mm f/3.5-5.6 IS Image Stabilized Lens