# Are Canon T2i lenses usable with 5D Mark II cameras?

Tags: lens, canon, cropped-sensor, full-frame

I presently own a Canon EOS t2i and I am looking to purchase the Canon EOS 5D Mark II. Are all my lenses compatible?

Comment: Though we don't know what lenses you have, this is likely answered already. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses for an explanation of the canon mounts and what can be used where.