# Broken Canon 28 -135 mm lens

Tags: lens, repair

I have a 28 - 135 mm Ultrasonic; the mechanism for the auto focus has failed, and there is some plastic bouncing around inside.

Is it worth repairing this lens?

Second question, assuming I don't get it repaired, I would like to replace it, but can't decide between the following:

- EF-S 18-135 IS STM
- Or replacing like for like (i.e. 28-135mm ultrasonic).

And lastly will either lens work with a full-frame 5D and the non-full-frame 7D?

Comment: The EF-S mount question is covered here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses

Comment: Hi there and welcome to photo.SE! You're unlikely to get helpful answers to this question as it stands for a couple of reasons: you're really asking 3 questions in one; you're not telling us everything we need to know (For example, what's your budget for the repair? What do you want to do with a replacement lens? etc.); and lastly, you're repeating questions that have already been asked. I recommend you follow @mattdm's link for the EF-S question then come back and edit this to make it easier to answer.

Comment: Have you called Canon or gone on their website for a repair estimate? What is the current price of this lens if you had to pick up a new or used one? These would be good things to look into to help make this decision.

Answer (score 2):

The EF 28-135 was the kit lens on bodies like the 50D. Its a better lens than the 18-55 F3.6-5.6 but its not a great lens. Its pretty slow.

The current used price on my local craigslist for the 28-135 is $200. You should check, but I expect the minimum repair cost is well over $100, so for me, its not worth fixing.

I replaced my 28-135 with the Canon 17-55 F2.8 and a 70-300. The 70-300 was $80 off craigslist. I love the 17-55 and the 70-300 is well worth what I paid for it.

Comment: I believe its an EF 28 - 135 not EF-s

Comment: You are right, its an EF, not EF-S, still, its only $440 new at B+H, and its a very average lens. Works well in bright light, but too slow for far too much of my shooting

Comment: I am guessing you replaced the 28-135 with a 17-55 f/2.8 and not an 18-55 f/2.8. I'm not aware of an 18-55 f/2.8 for Canon. They have 18-85, 17-55, and 17-50(sigma), but nothing 18-55 f/2.8.

Answer (score 1):

EF lens will work on full frame or non full frame cameras.

EF-S lens will work on crop sensors like the 7D,550D etc...

Exception for crop sensors are those tagged as pro cameras, they take EF lenses only.

Comment: Oh the EFS 18-135 is a good step up from the kit :D