# Upgrading from Canon T2i to Canon 6D

Tags: lens, canon-550d, compatibility, canon-6d

I want to upgrade my camera from Canon t2i to Canon 6D, Can I use the same lenses i already have ???

Lenses I own are,

1. Canon 58mm
2. Canon 75-300mm f/4.0-5.6 III AF
3. Canon-EF 50mm f/1.8 II
4. Rokinon 85mm  aspherical IF
5. Tamron SP 10-24mm 1:3.5 -4.5 (Wide angle lens)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses)

Answer (score 2):

You can use all lenses with a Canon "EF" mount. You cannot use lenses with a Canon "EF-s" mount; those lenses are for APS-C sensors only. The 6D is full format.

Answer (score 1):

Of the lenses you've got listed (assuming the 58mm is a close-up filter), you can use all of them except the Tamron 10-24.  The 10-24 will physically mount on a 6D (unlike, say, an EF-S 10-22), but the image circle will not be large enough to cover the 6D's sensor, and you will have vignetting.  All your other lenses are designed for full-frame.

However. The 75-300 III and the 50/1.8II are likely to look worse than you're used to seeing them o the T2i, now that the weaker corner performance is revealed.

Comment: Also note that even if the lens mounts some APS-C sized lenses rear element protrude deeper into the body than the 6D might allow (since it's mirror is considerably larger than that of a APC-C body) and might cause the mirror to hit the element and possibly damage it in the process.

Comment: Actually, reports of using the Tamron 10-24 or Tokina 11-16/2.8 on a full frame body do not mention mirror obstruction--only at what point in the zoom range the vignetting begins to show (typically around 15mm). From this, I'd assume there is no mirror obstruction with these specific lenses. I've had mirror obstruction with adapted film lenses, so I'm not sure that it's specific to crop lenses--it happens with adapted full frame lenses, too.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that this particular lens wouldn't hit the mirror. I just wanted to point this out just to be on the safe side :)

Answer (score 1):

T2i is an APS-C sensor camera while the 6D is a full-frame camera.
Will work with Full-frame camera:
- Rokinon 85mm aspherical IF
- Canon-EF 50mm f/1.8 II Telephoto Lens
- Canon 75-300mm f/4.0-5.6 III Autofocus Lens
- Canon 58mm lense (may be)

Will not work with full-frame:
- Tamron SP 10-24mm 1:3.5 -4.5 (Wide angle lense)

You can check all lenses you want at http://www.bhphotovideo.com. In the specifications tab, you'll find the mount compatibility.

Answer (score -2):

The Canon EOS 6D is a Full frame camera so only supports EF lenses, whereas the 550D (T2i) is a APS-C Camera body using EFS and EF lenses, therefore the 6D will not be compatible with all lenses the APSC bodies are compatible with.

Comment: While most of your answers are correctly revealing that the website you are linking to is your site (you forgot on this one...), we still frown somewhat on someone who seems to be using this site only to promote their products. Could you please try and also answer some questions which don't involve linking to your site?