# I have a Canon 1000D — will a lens compatible with a list of other cameras including the 100D, 700D, 1100D and others fit my camera?

Tags: canon, lens-mount, compatibility

I need a telephoto lens compatible with my Canon EOS 1000D.

Online shopping, I found an offer for a lens for "Canon Digital EOS Rebel SL1 (100D), T5i (700D), T4i (650D), T3 (1100D), T3i (600D), T1i (500D), T2i (550D), XSI (450D), XS (1000D), XTI (400D), XT (350D), 1D C, 70D, 60D, 60Da, 50D, 40D, 30D, 20D, 10D, 5D, Mark II, III, 1D X, 1D C, 1D Mark IV, 1D(s)Mark III, 1D(s)Mark II(N) , 5D Mark 2, 5D Mark 3, 7D, 6D Digital SLR Cameras." Is it also compatible with the Canon 1000D?

Comment: could you give us a little bit more information: What are you planning to shoot? Whats your budget, etc...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the list you provided explicitly lists the XS (**1000D**) as compatible, so your question is self-answering.

Comment: Is this a lens that mounts to the camera? Or  "lens" that screws onto the front of your existing lens?

Answer (score 1):

Any lens which is compatible with cameras in list is compatible with your Canon EOS 1000D. As far as I see cameras in the list have EF-S and EF socket. Your camera have EF-S socket and is compatible with EF and EF-S lens.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the whole point of interchangeable lens cameras is that a camera with mount X will fit any lens with mount X and vice versa.

There could be issues with third party manufacturers and the lens's electronics (aperture, image stabilisation, auto-focus, ...), as the communication standards typically are proprietary. The question ["Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y) has a lot more information on this potential issue.

There could also be problems with specifics within the same system - e.g. Nikon's F-mount features lenses that have to rely on a motor inside the camera, but recent low-price cameras do not offer this motor, as most lenses nowadays have their own motors.

Canon's EF-mounts, however, are pretty straightforward:

```
           / Lens (X) |
Camera (Y)            |  EF  | TS-E | MP-E | EF-S | EF-M | RF
----------------------|------|------|------|------|------|-----
                 EF   |  y   |  y   |  y   |  n   |  n   | n
                 EF-S |  y   |  y   |  y   |  y   |  n   | n
                 EF-M |  A   |  A   |  A   |  A   |  y   | n
                 RF   |  A   |  A   |  A   |  A   |  n   | y

(y...fits natively; n...does not fit; A...fits with adapter)
```

Incompatible Canon lenses will not even mount on your camera. If you wonder which mount your camera features, then the manual is a good starting point, as are questions such as ["What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses). In short, the EF-S mount on the camera features a white square indicator at ~ one o'clock in addition to the EF's red dot at 12 o'clock. EF-M has only a white dot at ~ 11 o'clock, and RF has a red line at 12 o'clock.

The EOS 1000D features an EF-S mount, so it can use EF and EF-S lenses. TS-E and MP-E both feature EF mounts, so as the table above shows, they are as compatible as EF lenses.

---

#### Short recap:

If your lens is made by Canon itself, then the lens's name will feature the mount (e.g. **EF-S** 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS STM) - more information can be found at ["What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean).

If your lens is made by a third party, then you should see what mount it offers.

We do not know for certain, but if the compatibility chart you offered is correct, not only is the 1000D featured (as it is listed), but also EF-mount cameras such as the 5D series. This means that it will probably feature an EF mount.

Comment: What about TS-E lenses? There are a lot more of them than the sole MP-E offering.