# What lenses are compatible with older Canon EOS DSLR?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount, compatibility

I own a Canon EOS 1100D camera that was released in 2011. What lenses are still compatible with this model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have a Canon 1000D — will a lens compatible with a list of other cameras including the 100D, 700D, 1100D and others fit my camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106176/i-have-a-canon-1000d-will-a-lens-compatible-with-a-list-of-other-cameras-inclu)

Comment: @bogl but is this a question that should be answered? As  I remember you are supposed to have do e some research prior to posting on stackexchange. Unless the research was to find out his first name then I'd say there is no effort or research done. A simple Google and open Wikipedia gives the answer to all questions.

Comment: @Andreas, probably not. It's rather low quality - as you are pointing out, and it's a duplicate - as scottbb is pointing out.

Comment: What lenses *are still* compatible? Bro, the Canon EOS line has had the same lens mount since the late 80’s. Unless you’re shopping the discount/retro film section, just about any Canon lens you hold should attach.

Comment: @Hueco there have been electrical/software compatibility issues, eg the whole sigma rechipping story... but that usually involved older lenses on newer bodies....

Comment: @Hueco 3rd party lenses have compatibility issues as already mentioned, and RF mount lenses are slowly starting to appear (and some EF-M mount lenses have appeared already), so certainly not all lenses are compatible.

Comment: @rackandboneman and I repeat myself...**just about any Canon lens you hold**. I didn't mention Sigma, did I? No? Didn't think so. If I wanted to spell out all the caveats instead of simply jest, I would have written an answer. MichaelC and xiota have done a fine job of that already.

Comment: @juhist See above response. Don't take what's obviously a little humor/jest as gospel.

Answer (score 5):

> I own a Canon EOS 1100D camera that was released in 2011. What lenses are still compatible with this model?

Canon EF lenses: All of them. Every single one made since 1987 when the EF mount was introduced.

Canon EF-S lenses: All of them. Every single one made since 2004 when EF-S lenses were introduced along with the EOS 20D.

Other lenses made by third party manufacturers for the EF/EF-S mount: Most of them made *since* the older camera in question appeared on the market. [There are sometimes compatibility problems](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/83122/15871) with *older* third party lenses and *newer* EOS (or Nikon, or Sony, or Pentax, Panasonic, Olympus, etc.) cameras. You would need to research a particular lens to see if any compatibility issues have been reported with your camera. Most are fairly well documented and easy to find with a proper internet search. In general you shouldn't have to worry about any third party EF lenses released since around 2011 when your EOS Rebel T3/1100D was introduced.

Comment: +1 for mentioning compatibility issues. One could of course underline that firmware updates may sometimes solve the issues of old third-party lenses and new camera bodies, but that doesn't help if the third-party lens is discontinued.

Answer (score 4):

- **Consider supporting your local economy by purchasing a lens at a local camera store.** Someone should be happy to assist you. Lenses are often organized by mount, so all lenses of interest should be located together. **You can try them in store to ensure they work with your camera.**
- When searching online, look for lenses that specifically state they are for **Canon EOS, EF, or EF-S**.

  - Avoid lenses that do *not* say they are compatible with Canon or that say they are compatible with a different brand.
  - Avoid lenses that say they are for Canon FL, FD, EF-M, EOS-M, or RF.  These are older (FL/FD) and newer (EOS-M/EF-M, RF) mounts that are not compatible with your camera.
- If a picture of the mount is shown in an item listing, compare it with your existing lens to make sure it matches. Note:

  - Apparent overall diameter.
  - Number and position of contacts.
  - Number and relative size of tabs.
  - Position of locking slot.
  - Presence of any mechanical linkages (there should be none).
- Canon EOS 1100D has an APS-C crop sensor (EF-S). It will work fine with lenses made for full frame (EF).
- See [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/76181/75526)